# Как вывести значения цикла после окончания

Tags: c++

Ребят, не подскажете, как сделать вывод из цикла итогового значения i,k,j?
Пробовал через присваивания другим переменным, но они остаются локальными внутри цикла

```
int num = 0; int num_3 = 0; int num_2 = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < size - 2; i++)
            {
                num = i;
                for (int j = 1; j < size - 1; j++)
                {
                    num_2 = j;
                    for (int k = 1; k < size; k++)
                    {
                        num_3 = k;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Ну, итоговые значения и так понятны - size-3, size-2 и size-1 :) Просто объявите `i,j,k` *вне* внешнего цикла. Если я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите (правда, не понимаю, зачем).

Comment: @Harry, у меня проблема была в том, что я размерность задавал 3, и цикл не начинался, спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Так цикл тоже будет работать:

```
 int i=0;         // объявили переменную за циклом, так что ее будет видно 
                  // и вне его. Хорошая практика - сразу сделать 
                  // присваивание.
 for(;i<size;++i) // из for всегда можно выкинуть любую часть, хоть все три -
 {                // он тогда станет бесконечным
 }
 cout << i << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = 0; 
int num_3 = 0; 
int num_2 = 0;
int i, j, k; // Объявляем переменные здесь

for (i = 1; i < size - 2; i++)
{
    num = i;
    for (j = 1; j < size - 1; j++)
    {
        num_2 = j;
        for (k = 1; k < size; k++)
        {
            num_3 = k;
        }
    }
}

// Теперь значения i, j и k доступны за пределами циклов
// Вы можете их использовать здесь
```

Comment: Постарайтесь в будущем оставлять более развернутые ответы.